# How can I get my C program running time in ms not s on Windows10?

Tags: c

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <Windows.h>

struct timeb timenow;

int main() {
    ftime(&timenow);
    printf("%ds %dms\n", timenow.time, timenow.millitm);
    Sleep(1503);
    ftime(&timenow);
    printf("%ds %dms\n", timenow.time, timenow.millitm);
    return 0;
}
```

Why the program always print 0 ms ？
The time is OK but the millitm is always 0.

Comment: [Your program worked on my Windows 10](https://i.imgur.com/23g1v4v.png). What is your compiler? Mine is gcc (GCC) 4.8.1.

Comment: Per the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftime.3.html) this function is obsolete and should be replaced by `clock_gettime`.

Comment: Works for me, too. (clang-cl in Visual Studio)

Comment: My initial compiler is MSVC.Now I try it by gcc.It runs successfully now.@MikeCAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ftime(3) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftime.3.html), the `time` member of `struct timeb` has the type `time_t`.

This type may be 64-bit long to support date beyond the year 2038.

On the other hand, typical `int` is 32-bit long.

The `%d` format specifier is for printing `int`, and passing `time_t` to that will invoke *undefined behavior* by passind data having wrong type.

Unfortunately `printf` doesn't seem to have proper format specifier to print `time_t`, so you should cast that to some type that can be safely printed via `printf`.

On the other hand, the `millitm` member is `unsigned short` and it will be promoted to `int`, so using `%d` fot that is fine.

Try this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct timeb timenow;

int main() {
    ftime(&timenow);
    printf("%" PRId64 "s %dms\n", (int64_t)timenow.time, timenow.millitm);
    Sleep(1503);
    ftime(&timenow);
    printf("%" PRId64 "s %dms\n", (int64_t)timenow.time, timenow.millitm);
    return 0;
}
```